# MVC View Error Java

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I'm trying to create an Onscreen telepad where people can press the keypad buttons and itll come up in the text box I haven't made the ActionListner for the keypad yet but I want it to show up in the view... Here's the code for the Keypad Panel and the View there is also a duration timer which I've managed to get working but can't put them into one view

Here's the Keypad Panel

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class KeypadPanel extends JPanel {

private JButton noStar;
private JButton noHash;
private JButton[] buttons;
private JButton C;
private JButton add;
private JPanel keypadPanel;

public KeypadPanel(TelepadController controller)  {

    buttons = new JButton[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i] = new JButton("" + i);
      //  buttons[i].addActionListener(controller.new NumberButtonListener());
    }

    //noStar.addActionListener(controller.new noStarActionListener);
    //noHash.addActionListener(controller.new noHashActionListener);
    //C.addActionListener(controller.new CActionListener);
    //add.addActionListener(controller.new addActionListener);


    noStar = new JButton("*");
    noHash = new JButton("#");
    C = new JButton("C");
    add = new JButton("+");


    JPanel keypadPanel = new JPanel();
    keypadPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3));
    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
         keypadPanel.add(buttons[i]);
            add(noStar);
    add(noHash);
  add(C);
 add(add);


    }
}
```

}

And here's the code for the main View

```
package londontelepad2;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource;
import javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource;
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;


public class TelepadView implements Observer {

private StopwatchPanel stopwatchPanel;
private KeypadPanel keypadPanel;
private JFrame frame;

/**
 *
 * @param controller
 */
public TelepadView(TelepadController controller) {

    super();
    this.setResources();

    frame = new JFrame("London Telepad");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    stopwatchPanel = new StopwatchPanel(controller);
    //stopwatchPanel = new StopwatchPanel2(controller);
    keypadPanel = new KeypadPanel(controller);

    frame.getContentPane().add(stopwatchPanel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(keypadPanel);
    frame.pack();
}

public void show() {
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void update(Observable observable, Object arg) {
    if (arg.equals(Properties.TIME)) {
        try {
            stopwatchPanel.setTime(BeanUtils.getProperty(observable,
                    Properties.TIME));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}

public void setResetState() {
    stopwatchPanel.setButtons(true, false, false);
}

public void setStoppedState() {
    stopwatchPanel.setButtons(false, false, true);

}

public void setRunningState() {
    stopwatchPanel.setButtons(false, true, false);
}

private void setResources() {

    ColorUIResource defaultBackground = new ColorUIResource(Color.white);
    ColorUIResource defaultForeground = new ColorUIResource(Color.black);
    ColorUIResource disabledColor = new ColorUIResource(Color.lightGray);

    FontUIResource smallFont = new FontUIResource(
            new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 12));
    FontUIResource bigFont = new FontUIResource(
            new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 14));

    UIManager.put("Button.background",
            defaultBackground);
    UIManager.put("Button.foreground",
            defaultForeground);
    UIManager.put("Button.disabledText",
            disabledColor);
    UIManager.put("Button.font", smallFont);


    UIManager.put("Label.background",
            defaultBackground);
    UIManager.put("Label.foreground",
            defaultForeground);
    UIManager.put("Label.font", bigFont);

    UIManager.put("Panel.background",
            defaultBackground);
    UIManager.put("Panel.foreground",
            defaultForeground);
}
}
```

If I do the .add seperately I get an error to do with (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

and if i do it together I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout: constraint must be a string (or null)

And I can't find what it is im doing wrong!!

All the help in the world would be very appreciated seeing as I'm an Uber noob at java!

Thank you

Bilal

UPDATE

Here's a log of the error I reciveve when I put them in the same .add field

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at londontelepad2.KeypadPanel.<init>(KeypadPanel.java:48)
at londontelepad2.TelepadView.<init>(TelepadView.java:46)
at londontelepad2.TelepadController.<init>(TelepadController.java:33)
at londontelepad2.LondonTelepad2.main(LondonTelepad2.java:19)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: do you have the log of the error??

Comment: Yes, just uploaded it now! @jpganz18

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wait, KeypadPanel is just a plain object. Why doesn't it extend JPanel?

you are calling the `add()`-method of a JFrame to add your components to the frame? You need to call

```
frame.getContentPane().add(comp);
```

Comment: You've lost me completely...sorry! `frame.add(keypadPanel);`doesnt it's when i do `frame.add(stopwatchPanel, keypadPanel);` it actually compiles but I get the error I posted above!

Comment: @ Bilal Haider: Did you ever made a Swing-Application? To me it looks like you tried to implement it in a different language...

Comment: @desperateCoder I wrote it the way my tutor wanted it to be written lol

Comment: Forget frame.add()!!! You probably never will need JFrames .add() - Method! If you want to add a Component into a JFrame, so _always_ get the contentPane and add your component into it! even if it compiles, it wont behave like you may expect.

Comment: @ Bilal Haider: WTF? Whats the matter with him?? Sounds like he was so frustrated about frame.add() did not work for him, so he decided to become an tutor?

Comment: @desperateCoder I've tried the .getContentPane and it still doesn't work. Unless I'm being really stupid and missed something! Lol, he's a bit weird!

Comment: sure it does not work! you need your Keypad-Panel to extend JPanel. a JPanel is a Component, so getContentPane.add() will know, how to handle it. additionally you should delete "keypadPanel = new JPanel();" and replace all occurrences of "keypadPanel.add(XY);" by "add(XY);" (since your KeypadPanel is a JPanel now, you can easyly add components to itself)

Comment: @desperateCoder you've completely lost me again! Sorry, where do I add the extend? I get the add but not the extend! You guys probably think I'm useless at this! lol

Comment: a class can extend an other one. so you can write: public class KeypadPanel extends JPanel {... Dont worry, i'm sure, you are very good at something, i cant even spell!

Comment: @desperateCoder ok I've got the the four buttons outside of the loop to be entered and showing but my numbers (1-0) aren't showing and neither is my timer now! Aghhh this is stressful

Comment: it is hard to keep track of your changes, so could you please post your new code into your question?

Comment: sure they won't, since you have forgotten to remove "keypadPanel." in the for-loop adding the buttons. I told you to delete "JPanel keypadPanel = new JPanel();" from your code :P

Comment: Ok so I removed the "JPanel keypadPanel = new JPanel();" but it's still not showing! :(, might just run to Photoshop lol @desperateCoder

Comment: did you remove "keypadPanel." from the line "keypadPanel.add(buttons[i]);" too?

Comment: not sure which error you mean, but your two for-loops: why do you run the first one from 0 to 9, but the second one from 1 to 9?

Comment: @desperateCoder the "exception" thing, just noticed that. Changed them both to 0 to 9

Comment: null-pointer: there are no line-numbers shown above, but a varable at line 48 of your keypadpanel is not initialized or null.

Comment: thats the "keypadPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3));" @desperateCoder Shall I change the kepadPanel to something else? I got rid of the keypadPanel = new Jpanel too so It might be something to do with the set layout thing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29849/discussion-between-bilal-haider-and-desperatecoder)

Comment: the site is blocked in here, sorry, maybe at evening? Anyway: you have to remove that keypadPanel-Object **completely**. assume, the KeyPadPanel-Class is your new panel. so you can remove "keypadPanel." and there will be no problem! just call "setLayout(new...)"